# Prove that $|Av|\ge c|v|$ for all $v$ in the vector space $V$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, proof-verification

If $A \in Lin(V,W)$ is invertible (that is, a linear isomorphism) and $c =||A^{-1}||^{-1}$, prove that $|Av|\ge c|v|$ for all $v$ in the normed vector space $V$.

So I know that $||A|| = \sup\{|Ax|/|x| : x\ne 0\}$.

Basically I need to show that $|Av|\ge \frac{|v|}{||A^{-1}||}$.

So if I let $0\ne x \in V$ be the vector such that $||A^{-1}||=|A^{-1}x|/|x|$. Then $|Av|\ge \frac{|v|}{||A^{-1}||} = \frac{|v|}{|A^{-1}x|/|x|} \implies$

$|Av||A^{-1}|\ge|v||x|\implies |v||x|\ge|v||x|$ which is true, but I have my doubts. Is this correct?

Comment: A vector $x \in V$ such that $||A^{-1}|| = |A^{-1}(x)|/|x|$ doesn necessarily exist. There's a reason there's $\sup$ instead of $\max$.

Comment: Also, your chain of implication starts from the conclusion, while you probably want to _end_ with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we need to work in a Banach space to say that $\|A^{-1}\|<\infty$ by open mapping theorem (for example finite dimensional space) so :
$$
\|A^{-1} x\|\leq \|A^{-1}\| \|x\|= c^{-1} \|x\| \qquad \forall x\in W
$$
so let $y\in V$ we put  $x=Ay$,  then we have :
$$
\|y\|= \|A^{-1} A y\|\leq c^{-1} \|Ay\| 
$$